# Multicoloramp in same object?

Tags: materials

hello !

I'm looking to use 2 color gradients, I know how to use a colorramp on an XYZ axis on an object, but I would like to add a second color gradient in another direction. for example I have a gradient from left to right and another gradient from top to bottom. an example is worth 1000 word here is what I want to do, I have my gradient on my X axis I would like it on the Y axis, how to make my Material in Eevee?

[image]

Comment: I can think of two general approaches that might be worth exploring: 1. Use one gradient that depends on both X and Y values. The most basic example I can think of would be using a radial gradient texture instead of a linear gradient. 2. Choose how to mix colors based on X and Y. Since there isn't a "2D ColorRamp" node, instead generate and X gradient and a Y gradient. Then blend the two together. The blending could just be mixing the colors together with a MixRGB node, or something more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

you can do a "kind of" gradient as you want like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

The problem of two textures with different colors is:
You have to mix the colors "somehow". So i decided to use these multiply/modulo/less-than nodes to only paint some coordinate rows with either the upper or the lower colorramp colors. If you don't use this technique, you have to mix the colors somehow, which looked worse...

[image]

at least if you use mix mode for the colors as i did. But i will be happy if someone can provide a technique which mixes the colors in a way that the 4 colors in the gradient are still good looking in the result.

Here the results, if you make the rows thinner:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][8]][8]

[image]

[image]